DLL load failed while importing _psycopg
I've tried, postgres and py reinstall, psycopg2 and binary reinstall, anaconda, ps bin, visual c++
2 days with this problem, i cant import library psycopg2
Error al importar psycopg2: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
I have heard, maybe the version of the OS.

try:
    import psycopg2
    print("psycopg2 importado correctamente.")
except ImportError as e:
    print("Error al importar psycopg2:", e)


Error al importar psycopg2: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg:
No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

